# What anime is this keyholder coming from?

Tags: merchandise

I brought this keyholder from an anime shop a few years ago but not able to ask which anime it came from.

[image][image]

<sup>Front view | Back view</sup>

I tried translating it, and it says "rakorafura", and tried to search the internet for it but no luck. I also tried a reverse image search.

Maybe it's not an anime?

Comment: btw it looks more like churafura (チュラフラ) to me. I couldn't find anything by searching for it, though

Comment: That looks very similar to the DRRR!! (デュラララ!!) logo, but it's missing the dakuten on デ, and the テ looks different as well as the 2nd ラ being a フ. No copyright anywhere, so I think this is just a knock-off (though I can't say the front is from the series either...).

Answer (score 7):

The text on the back *supposed to be* referring to **the *Durarara!!* (デュラララ!!) series**.

[image]

However, the title logo was crafted poorly; it's missing the dakuten on デ, looking more like テ, and the second ラ seems squished, looking more like フ. Also, browsing for "medal", "pendant", and "keyholder" didn't return any results that look like the front view. This seems like unofficial or even unrelated merchandise using the name of the series.

Compared to [the official merchandises](https://www.broccoli.co.jp/news/1009/23_goods_key_drrr.html) by Broccoli Co., Ltd.

[image]